# What is the problem with how i am going about verifying my contract i just deployed?

Tags: contract-deployment, contract-verification

Im having troubles verifying and my constructor arguments and ABI have been triple checked. Can anyone assist? here is what im getting on polygonscan.

Compiler debug log:
Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI
Found the following ContractName(s) in source code : Address, Context, ContractName, ERC165, ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, IERC165, IERC721, IERC721Enumerable, IERC721Metadata, IERC721Receiver, Ownable, Strings
But we were unable to locate a matching bytecode (err_code_2)
For troubleshooting, you can try compiling your source code with the Remix - Solidity IDE and check for exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be tricky. From what I understand it cannot find a byte-for-byte match. The match has to be over the whole `tx.data` that you sent. This includes constructor code and parameters, plus the deployed code.

1. Did you write the contracts in the proper order so that they are declared before they are used? (I think yes)
2. Did you properly enter the constructor parameters, like 0x1234..., and without a potential Swarm appendage? (If you had constructor parameters)
3. Are you sure about the version and optimisation runs used by the compiler? (Check in your computer folder for a `.json` file that could tell you that)

Comment: The contract should be in proper order. The constructor parameters have been triple checked same with ABI so that should be good. As for the compiler that is the correct one too. hmm..

Comment: Can you perhaps update your question with a github repo for the code and the address Etherscan link?

Comment: Please provide 
1. Code
2. Deployed Address
3. Consturctor passed
4. Optimizer : on/off